# Wikidata: Filter post codes only current valid

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I would like to filter post codes to show only the current active for today.

Problem is there are are cities with old post codes ([Example](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q32752658#P281)).

My current query shows the old post codes:

```
SELECT ?city ?cityLabel ?postcode ?federal_stateLabel ?federal_state_nr WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],de". }
  ?city (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q7930989;
    wdt:P17 wd:Q183;
    wdt:P281 ?postcode;
    wdt:P131 ?federal_state.
  ?federal_state wdt:P439 ?federal_state_nr.
}
ORDER BY (?postcode)
LIMIT 10
```

([query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org/#%0ASELECT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fpostcode%20%3Ffederal_stateLabel%20%3Ffederal_state_nr%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cde%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20%28wdt%3AP31%2F%28wdt%3AP279%2A%29%29%20wd%3AQ7930989%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ183%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP281%20%3Fpostcode%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP131%20%3Ffederal_state.%0A%20%20%3Ffederal_state%20wdt%3AP439%20%3Ffederal_state_nr.%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%28%3Fpostcode%29%0ALIMIT%2010))

I would have to use [start time P580](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P580) and [end time P582](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P582) but I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this for filtering out the claims which have an end time:

```
?city p:P281 ?postCodeStmt .
?postCodeStmt ps:P281 ?postcode .
FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?postcode pq:P582 ?endTime . }
```

The whole query becomes:

```
SELECT ?city ?cityLabel ?postcode ?federal_stateLabel ?federal_state_nr WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],de". }
  ?city (wdt:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q7930989;
    wdt:P17 wd:Q183;
    p:P281 ?postCodeStmt;
    wdt:P131 ?federal_state.
  ?federal_state wdt:P439 ?federal_state_nr.
  ?postCodeStmt ps:P281 ?postcode.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?postCodeStmt pq:P582 ?endTime . } # Filtering out old postal codes
}
ORDER BY (?postcode)
LIMIT 100
```

See also [Wikidata:SPARQL tutorial§Qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial#Qualifiers).